# C# Regex to extract all words that begin with numbers and are contained in a specific list?

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

Given a collection of word combinations, is it possible to return a collection of matched word sets and extract those from a given string using RegEx?

For example, given a car list:

```
mazda 3
mazda 4
volvo s40
```

The following text is used:
"I wanted to buy a mazda 3 however I found the volvo s40 to be a much better deal with the 90gv tires."

I how want two different lists from this that should return:

```
{mazda 3, volvo s40, 90gv} 
{I, wanted, to, buy, a, however, I, found, the, to, be, a, much, better, deal, with, the, tires}
```

Comment: These are not words that begin with a number. These are words that are followed by a space and a number, and a list of all remaining words. To be an effective coder you need to learn to state the problem space better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses a MatchEvaluator for the matches (the car models), and returns "", so the model gets replaced with empty string.  `cars` is a list of car models. `words` is a list of the remaining words.  I'll leave it to you to handle punctuation appropriately for your needs.

```
List<string> cars = new List<string>();
string input =
   "I wanted to buy a mazda 3 however I found the volvo s40 to be a much better deal.";
string line = Regex.Replace(
   input, @"\b\w+\s+(?=\S*?\d)(?:\w+)",
   m =>
      {
         cars.Add(m.Value);
         return "";
      });
string [] words = line.Split(' ');

// Ouput the lists:
Console.Write ("Cars:");
foreach (string car in cars)
   Console.Write(car + "    ");
Console.WriteLine ();
Console.Write ("words: ");
foreach (string word in words)
   Console.Write(word + " ");
```

Produces this output:

```
Cars:mazda 3    volvo s40
words: I wanted to buy a  however I found the  to be a much better deal.
```

Comment: that works great... but how would you write the regexp to, along with this, to return any words beginning with a number that are not in the list of cars... so that 3 (from mazda 3) is not returned separately, and as edited above, "90gv" would be returned part of the car list?

Comment: How can you tell the difference between words that should be returned (like mazda and volvo) and non-makes like `the 90gv` ?  You want to pass those into the function?

Comment: I see what you're saying.  I think this may work for what I want to accomplish.  have to test.  Thank you.

Comment: Agent:  My regex kung fu is weak...  it possible to keep the existing functionality, and add anything in quotations to the CARS list? So if you had "however I found the" - that would be placed as part of the CARS list?

Comment: @ElHaix, do you mean `I wanted to buy a mazda 3 "however I found the" volvo s40...`?  So you would get `mazda 3`, `"however I found the"`, and `volvo s40`?

Comment: @Agent: yes that is correct.  Upon further testing today, what if what if it's a mazda 3.3?  Currently is separates this to "mazda 3" and ".3"  where it should be all together.